# Remove AngularJS Default Click Box

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, button, onclick

I have a simple ng-click directive that's working as intended, however when I click one of the elements (the stars below) a blue selection box appears. The element is an md-icon. How do I remove/hide this selection box?

[image]

Here's the element:

```
<md-icon ng-click="starClicked(i)" ng-repeat="i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]" id="rate-course-star-{{i}}" ng-mouseover="starMouseHovered(i)" ng-mouseleave="starMouseLeft(i)">star_rate</md-icon>
```

The same sized selection box appears when any star is clicked, is positioned such that the clicked star is the furthest left in the box.

Comment: Try to see if the css :active and :focus for those stars class have some border property. Can you prepare a fiddle?

Comment: @Dario No need, I went around it by wrapping it in an md-button and then resizing it and what not. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this I wrapped it in an `<md-button>`.